# Error trying to install headless dropbox on unix server

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, dropbox, headless

Getting the below error trying to install dropbox in a unix headless environment

*.dropbox-dist/dropbox: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")*

Instructions followed: http://www.dropboxwiki.com/Text_Based_Linux_Install#Step-by-step_version

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when you are trying to install a 64-bit dropbox version on a 32-bit unix server. Double-check that you are grabbing the correct dropbox version for your server architecture

Comment: This is the correct answer. It needs to be marked as such.